# C# HttpWebRequest authenticate against htaccess protected page and handle redirect

Tags: c#, .net, .htaccess, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication

I'm trying to write code for a page on our website which will pass users through to an htacess protected page on another site and programmatically authenticate.  This is my first time doing something like this, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.  I have the following info from the owners of the third party platform:

url: https://[domain]/library/
username: [username], password: [password]

Originally I was trying to add the basic authentication as a base64 encoded string in the webrequest header and that wasn't working (I was getting a 401 unauthorized error), and I received this info from the third party:

I’ve reviewed the code you’ve provided again and cross checked against the documentation on MSDN. I’ve found two items that might help.

1. HttpWebRequest does not pass along any headers named “Authorization”, for security reasons. Instead, set the “Credentials” property to an instance of the “NetworkCredential” class. You’ll have to convert the password to a SecureString.
2. Our server issues a redirect to “https://[domain]/library/”, with a slash at the end. Again, for security reasons, HttpWebRequest will not honor the “Credentials” property over a redirect. You need to provide the final URI in your WebRequest.Create call.

After following the guidance from these items, I was able to get a 200 OK response from our server with the modified code. Please let me know if you have any further difficulties.

After that guidance, I made sure the slash was present in my URI and switched to using NetworkCredential, and I was able to get a successful response.  However, when I tried to redirect to the response URI, it was still presenting the popup to enter login info.  I tried switching from NetworkCredential to CredentialCache, but that didn't help.  My current test code, where sp is the SecureString created from [password]:

```
NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential([username], sp);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(https://[domain]/library/);
//myCredentials.Domain = [domain];
//req.Credentials = myCredentials;
var cache = new CredentialCache { { new Uri(https://[domain]/library/), "Basic", myCredentials } };
req.Credentials = cache;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
ViewBag.mssg += "Request to Url is sent.Waiting for response...";
    
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
ViewBag.mssg += "Response received successfully." + resp.ResponseUri + resp.StatusCode;
resp.Close();
    
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.ResponseUri.ToString()))
{
  Response.Redirect(resp.ResponseUri.ToString());
}
else
{
  throw new Exception("invalid redirect");
}
```

The newest advice from the third party is:

It looks like you’re missing credentials for the redirect, effectively bypassing all the work you’ve done thus far on authentication. You’ll need to add the credentials to the UserInfo property of the response URI as otherwise the browser can’t use them.

However, I'm unsure how to use that info.  Do I need to issue a second web request to the same URI with the UserInfo property attached?  Is there anything I'm missing or setting incorrectly in the original request?  Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the `UserInfo` property? Part of the URL?

Comment: You are creating a proxy server.  See : https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/GWS/Content/Overview/Getting_Started/Sending_Proxy_Server_Credentials_in_NET.htm